# Character gets stranded with polygon collider in sloped platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have used polygon collider for the hills and terrain like sprite in my 2d game.
I used the same polygon collider for my hero character. Here is my problem the movement is smooth when i used box collider in hills and all that but it makes my character look like floating in air. so i opt to use polygon collider for hills.

However polygon collider produces some small pit or irregular shape to fix the best possible shape of collider for hill. Here my player or hero get stuck in those pits or irregular shape. Even the slightest pit cause my player to strand. I tried various way to mitigate all those errors but no any result.

Please suggest to me some way to make my character movement smooth in uphill.

Comment: Well, the ultra-hi-tech way to improve uphill movement would be to use inverse kinematics so his feet can either stretch out to a section of ground below him, or compress to a section of ground farther up than his origin. There's likely information around the web about "how games get characters to go up staircases"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using one collider, try 2 different ones for your player. Put a box collider around his mid section and head, and a circle/capsule collider that goes around his feet. That way you get the circle/capsule collider will reduce the chance of your player getting stuck on awkward locations :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to edit the collider yourself, or even start with an EdgeCollider and make the shape yourself. Anyway, I don't know how irregular those "pits" are, but you can always edit in a very easy way the collider in 2D.

Oh, and you can edit the collider in the component itself, and then in the editor window.